# replace String to number in loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to create a fill in the blank quizz web site. 
My problem is putting a different name="" value of all inputs.

So I create a function Who change a string giving into input.
But the problem is they have all the same name (inpName1). 
What I want to do is giving them a diffrent names (inpName1,inpName2,inpName3...) so I can recuperate them later into DB

```
var i=0; 
function MyFunction() {            
  var str = document.getElementById("myTextArea").value; 
  var res = str.replace(/#champ/g, "<input type='text' name='inpName"+ i++ +"'>");
  document.getElementById("finalText").innerHTML = res;

}
```

Comment: You might want to use an object. I don't think you can create a dynamic variable

Comment: It would probably be much easier to use the same name on all of them, and treat the input as an array. If you make the name `inpName[]`, then when submitted to PHP, it will treat all the results as an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `inpName1`, `inpName2` etc use `[]` notation in `name` attribute:

```
<input type='text' name='inpName[]'>
<input type='text' name='inpName[]'>
<input type='text' name='inpName[]'>
<input type='text' name='inpName[]'>
```

In this case your values will be available on server via `$_POST['inpName']` array.